# Jackson Object Mapper - "Missing type id " on concrete class deserialization without explicit type info property

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have the following object structure:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "@type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") })
interface Animal {
    String name = null;
}    

@JsonTypeName("dog")
class Dog implements Animal {
    public double barkVolume;
    public String name;
}

class Zoo {
    public Animal animal;
    public Dog thisIsDog;
}
```

and I want to deserialize the following JSON file into `Zoo` class:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "@type": "dog",
        "barkVolume": 12.0,
        "name": "my dog;"
    },
    "thisIsDog": {
        "barkVolume": 12.0,
        "name": "my dog;"
    }
}
```

as follows:

```
Zoo newObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Zoo.class);
```

but I get this error:

```
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.test.Dog]: 
missing type id property '@type' (for POJO property 'thisIsDog')
```

and if I add `"@type": "dog",` to `thisIsDog` node of course everything work... but I don't want to. I believe Jackson should have the info about the type because it's explicitly defined in `Zoo` class, no?

I feel I'm missing an attribute of some sort.. but can't figure out which one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting defaultImpl on JsonTypeInfo.

Comment: that won't work for me in general (because I obviously don't have dogs and cats but more elaborated structure). I have 3 classes which I use either directly on a field, or via a common interface...  But thank you for prompt reply.

Comment: Dog inherits the JsonTypeInfo from Animal. So it must be set. Maybe you can override the Annotation with defaultImpl in Dog

Comment: Same problem for me, did you find any fix?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any luck on what annotation was missing?